# "Your Google Developers Console project is scheduled for deletion" - Will this remove my project from Google Play too?

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services, google-play-games, google-developer-tools

I can recover my account within 7 days. I think that Google Developer Console and Google **Play** Developer Console are not linked together, but I need to know for sure.

I know that **Play** Developer Console uses this project for SHA1 verification, but is it the same project?

Could anyone give me certainty about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did this a couple of times. My Google Play app never was deleted. Your Developer Console project is "SHA1 Verification". And your Play Console project is "Your App". A deletion will result into: "No SHA1 verification for your app."

Comment: What exactly do I need the SHA1 verification for? For the app itself also? Or for Google API services alone?

Comment: I think it is an evidence that your app is "your app". Services, like "Google Play Games" requires a verification (without the verification this app would not run). What are you doing in your app?

Comment: Yes, but this verification is done within Google Play Developer console itself, correct?

Comment: "... then your client application requests an access token from the Google Authorization Server, extracts a token from the response, and sends the token to the Google API that you want to access. For an interactive demonstration of using OAuth 2.0 with Google (including the option to use your own client credentials), experiment with the OAuth 2.0 Playground." I think for API calls it is still required.